# Used MacPorts version of gcc and MacPorts version of python

Tags: python, gcc, installation, macports, theano

I am installing theano on Mavericks using macports.
One of the installation step is to use macport version of python  and gcc.
I am not sure where is the path of the macport python.

```
sudo port select python python27
which python 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python"
```

usually macport save package on under `/opt/local/bin/`

in the .bash_profile file I have these lines

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7

    # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
    PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
    export PATH
```

and under `/opt/local/bin/`, there  is binary file `python2.7`

So what it the version corresponding to Macport?

**for gcc**
I have the same confusion:

Available versions for gcc:
sudo port select gcc 
    mp-gcc47
    mp-gcc49 (active)
    mp-gcc5
    none
and

```
  which gcc
  "/usr/bin/gcc"
```

and under `/opt/local/bin` I have a binary file `gcc`

Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts adds `export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"` to the end of `~/.profile`, so that `/opt/local/bin` is searched first.

Clearly, if you override this by prepending for instance `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` to the `PATH`, then `python` will be found in that directory first. You can run `which -a python` by the way to show all available python executables.

So, one way to "fix" this issue is to move the path setting for python into `~/.profile` above the entry for MacPorts -- or to simply comment it out.

I assume there is some similar path issue with `gcc`.